# Django - changes which I do in static files don't appear immediately

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Something really strange happening with my Django environment, recently. After I updated Django from 1.9 to 1.10 and updated PyCharm to latest version I have a problem with static files. When I writing change both in css or js files, I don't see those changes immediately on apps. I need manually run direct link to one of those files in browser(for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/main.css) and after that I can see changes.

Before updates all worked correctly and I have seen all changes in static files immediately.

settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
        '/static/',
    )

urls

```
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Just guessing: could it be the browser's caching which is still turned on?

Comment: I didn't do anything with browser settings... It worked normally for lately but now doesn't. I couldn't say that I can't work but that "staticfiles" behavior really irritate me.

Comment: Did you try opening you web page in an incognito window or a different browser? If it does, the caching might be the problem...